# CakePhP and jquery.getJSON how to pass data to controller

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp

I use jquery 1.8.3 and cakephp2, i have problem to pass data to controller by ajax this is my code:

*.js

```
     $.getJSON("json/", {data: "somedata"}, function (data) {
        console.log(data['data']);
        d = data;
    }).error(function() { alert("error"); })
```

*controller.php:

```
public function json($site = null)
{
    $data = Array(
        "name" => $site,
    );
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $this->set(compact('data', $data));
}
```

view.ctp:

```
<?php 
    $this->autoRender = false;    
    echo json_encode(compact('data', $data)); 
?>
```

but in console name variable is null, anyone know how to do it right?
thx for any help!

Comment: data in getJson should be of the format name=Value. eg param1=foo&param2=bar

Comment: thx, but still it doesn't work

Comment: You ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your controller:

```
return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode($data)));
```

Comment: problem is not here, $site variable in json() controller is null, but it should be $site = "somedata"